# Webjobs SDK Beta - Is Nagle supported?

Tags: asp.net, azure-webjobs, nagle

Does the Webjobs SDK support disabling the Nagle algorithm?
I have read the article here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/06/25/nagle-s-algorithm-is-not-friendly-towards-small-requests.aspx and I wonder if it is possible to turn this off to improve performance with small message sizes?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible. We are considering various configuration options for a future release.